# Check for req.files object empty

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload

I am uploading file through express-fileupload. My file gets uploaded successfully if I am not checking for req.files as empty. But I am getting one error as when I am going to check for req.files as empty. I am posting my code as referenace.

```
if(req.files.length > 0){

    console.log('file is exist');

    var file_name = req.files.filetoupload;

    file_name.mv("public/uploads/"+ file_name.name, function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            var profile_pic_name = '';
        } else {
            var profile_pic_name = file_name.name;
        }
    });
}
else
{
    console.log('file not exist');
    var profile_pic_name = '';
}
```

So when I am trying to upload a file it goes in else section and prints "file not exist" on console. So my main concern is how to check if req.files is empty or not.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I don't know if I understood correctly your question.

Try something like that:

`req.files && req.files.length`

I hope this help, If this doesn't meet your necessity let me know

Comment: No this is not working. Actully my concern is if I am uploading file then it should go in if statement and should print "file is exist". But it goes in else statement.

Comment: @Yogeshk Do you configure the middleware. `app.use(fileUpload());`?

Comment: Yes. Actually. I dont have problem with file uploading. Its working fine. Main issue is with checking for req.files as empty or not

Comment: On my env, req.files is always true, and req.files.lenght is always false :/

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve that using a conditional ternary operator.

 
For instance, below sample code print "Non Empty File" if **req.files** exists or "Empty file" if **req.files** is empty.

**`req.files ? console.log('Non Empty File') : console.log('Empty file');`**

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this and find out if the file exists or not.

```
if (!req.files) {
  // File does not exist.
  console.log("No file");
} else {
  // File exists.
  console.log("File exists");
}
```

Comment: Problem is that req.files is always an object when the Form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` so it's always true, even if no file was uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

```js
try {
  var file_name = req.files.filetoupload;

  file_name.mv("public/uploads/"+ file_name.name)
} catch (error) {
  res.send(`File not found`)
}
```

Use the try and catch method and it works...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
 const uploadPhoto = req.files.photo ? `images/${req.files.photo[0].filename}` : "";
```